# python mysql error " mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Parameters for query must be list or tuple"

Tags: python, mysql

I am so confused in regards to this issue, as I have followed recommendations from other posts yet am unable to get my program to work!

```
        sql = "SELECT UserID FROM userdetails WHERE Username = %(value)s 
        AND Password = %(value2)s "
        params = {'value': username, 'value2': password}

        mycursor.executemany(sql, (params))

        mydb.commit()
```

I believe the error to be related to this section of the code yet I am unable to see any mistakes to fix in order to make the program work again!

Any help is very appreciated, thank you in advance :)

Comment: `cursor.executemany` expects the sql and a list or tuple of parameter collections in order to generate multiple queries.  You are only passing a single parameter collection, so use the `cursor.execute` method instead, which will accept the parameter dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn´t use the `executemany` because it is used to execute the same statement (with different parameters) multiple times and usually used for `INSERTs` or `UPDATEs`, not for `SELECTs`.
You need to use the `execute` only:

```
 sql = "SELECT UserID FROM userdetails WHERE Username = %(value)s 
        AND Password = %(value2)s "
        params = {'value': username, 'value2': password}

 mycursor.execute(sql, (params))    
 mydb.commit()
```

Also, after a `SELECT` statement, you don´t need to do a `commit` (there is nothing to commit), but you will need to `fetch` the results of your query, so it will look like this:

```
 sql = "SELECT UserID FROM userdetails WHERE Username = %(value)s 
        AND Password = %(value2)s "
        params = {'value': username, 'value2': password}

 mycursor.execute(sql, (params))    
 data = mycursor.fetchall()
```